# Confused about the answers to two logic problems

Tags: logic, propositions, propositional-logic

1. True or False? If monkeys can fly, then 1 + 1 = 3.
2. What is logically equivalent to all x (p(x) + ~q(x))?

For the first one I think it is False.

Comment: 1) is true. Think about true conditionals as promises that were upheld. I promise you that if monkeys can fly, then 1+1 is equal to 3. Did I violate my promise? No, because I would violate it only if monkeys could fly, but 1+1 would still not be equal to 3. But this didn't happen.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to True before I turned it in,

Comment: @user161005 - Are you assuming the "if A then B" formulation in English is equivalent to a logical proposition of the form A -> B? If this is a homework problem then probably that was the intent, but conditionals can also be interpreted in terms of [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) which deals with possible worlds, David Lewis [apparently developed](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2214616) a modal logic analysis of conditionals...it isn't true that in a possible world where monkeys can fly, 1+1=3, so I assume the statement wouldn't be true under this sort of translation.

Comment: What needs to be understood here is that this is a math thing & a bunch of people are getting confused about.  When the average Speaker of English hears the word true or false they THINK IN REALITY.  So they are confused with the “only in this math class scenario” which is NOT EXPLICITLY STATED as distinct from true in reality. So what the math person MEANS is TRUE OR FALSE BY TRUTH TABLE only. had that been explicitly explained so many human being would not be getting confused. Tell the student to study truth tables, then draw a truth table for the following statements. That would be so easy.

Comment: @Logikal Decisions made by Aristotelians and Scholastics are not 'a math thing'.    Ex Falso Quodlibet has a long and honored history outside math, or it wouldn't have a Medieval Latin name. The Classical rules like this one, the Excluded Middle, and the rest of these untranslated or strangely translated named rules exist to simplify reasoning, and they focus on avoiding contradiction over preserving trust.  But they did so long before logic was a branch of mathematics.  And people argued about them then, too.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  Modal logic is the least relevant domain where these two things are not equivalent.  Constructive and Intuitionistic logics weaken negation in such a way that this kind of thing is no longer  true: a proof is a proof if it preserves trust, rather than if it cannot be confuted.  And they do it  without mixing in other issues.

Comment: (I am a constructivist at heart, so despite the tone, this is not attacking you, it is preaching...)

Comment: @jobermark, thanks for your comment. I stated what I stated because too many people are thinking logic is solely math and math is solely logic. This is objectively wrong. People did reason deductively before Mathematical logic was invented. Some people believe otherwise. The way they Express themselves. All subjects use deductive reasoning. Math is usually the first thing some people think of first though. It shouldn't be but whatever. Math doesn't own logic or have exclusive rights and people need to know that. So many students of math have thoughts like that. Why so many? Something is wrong.

Comment: One question at a time.

Comment: @user9166 "*Decisions made by Aristotelians and Scholastics are not 'a math thing'. Ex Falso Quodlibet has a long and honored history outside math, or it wouldn't have a Medieval Latin name*" To present Ex Falso Quodlibettalk as *Aristotelian* and *Scholastics* is fallacious. Ex Falso Quodlibet has been proposed by ONE Scholastic, William of Soissons, and criticised by most others. As to Aristotle, I doubt he would have approved.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions.

1. True or False? If monkeys can fly, then 1 + 1 = 3.

The antecedent of the conditional, "monkeys can fly" is false. So is the consequent, "1 + 1 = 3". In classical truth-functional logic the conditional connecting these two sentences also has a truth-value.  Wikipedia describes this "material conditional" as follows:

> The material conditional (also known as material implication, material consequence, or simply implication, implies, or conditional) is a logical connective (or a binary operator) that is often symbolized by a forward arrow "→".

This binary operator would return *true*, based on the [truth table Wikipedia provides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table). This is because the material conditional is defined to be false only when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. Otherwise, even when the conditional doesn't make sense, it is defined as true.

Because the antecedent and the consequent are unrelated there may be objections to assigning a truth-value to such a statement or to assigning the value true. See the [Wikipedia entry for relevance logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic) or the [SEP article on relevance logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/) for a discussion.

2. What is logically equivalent to all x (p(x) + ~q(x))?

I assume the statement is *∀x(P(x) v ¬Q(x)*.

Using [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Logical_equivalences) of logical equivalences suggests a conditional that would be logically equivalent to the disjunction.

> p ⟹ q ≡ ¬p ∨ q

Since ¬p ∨ q is logically equivalent to p ⟹ q, p v ¬q should be logically equivalent to ¬p ⟹ ¬q.  This suggest that *∀x(P(x) v ¬Q(x)* is logically equivalent to *∀x(¬P(x) ⟹ ¬Q(x)*.

For added confirmation, one can use a [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) to see if one could derive such an equivalence:

[image]

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, May 27). Material conditional. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 18:44, August 11, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Material_conditional&oldid=898972669

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

*Please note that my answer is entirely based on my personal expertise, and therefore not necessarily always representative of all logicians from Aristotle to the Scholastic, and definitely not of mathematical logic*.

---

> True or False? If monkeys can fly, then 1 + 1 = 3.

This argument is not formally valid (see note).

Validity is assessed on form. Nothing in the form of this argument could help us decide whether the antecedent "*monkeys can fly*" is true or false and whether the consequent "*1 + 1 = 3*" is true or false. Thus, the four basic combinations of a true or false antecedent and a true or false consequent are all a priori possible.

In particular, it is formally possible that the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, which makes the implication *If monkeys can fly, then 1 + 1 = 3* false in this case, and thus not valid.

You could make the antecedent *formally* false, as was probably your intention, by modifying it as follows:

> It is false that monkeys can fly;
>
> It is true that monkeys can fly;
>
> Therefore, 1 + 1 = 3.

As rephrased, the argument now has contradictory premises, making the *conjunction* of the premises false, and this irrespective of whether monkeys can or cannot in fact fly.

According to most methods in mathematical logic, arguments with contradictory premises (or a false antecedent) are all *valid*.

---

According to my own experience, however, it is clear that most people who are not trained in mathematical logic will say that the argument is not valid. Many people will even say that the argument doesn't make sense, which is somewhat stronger since it implies that it is also not valid.

So, you may want to keep in mind that the theoretical definition of validity used in mathematical logic isn't equivalent to what most people have in mind.

I would certainly recommend not to walk into a bar on a Saturday night to use arguments with contradictory premises to try and convince big guys with tattoos there that their logic is just wrong because mathematical logic says so.

On the other hand, if you plan to have a career in mathematics, may be you can try to see the good side of the definition of validity as used in mathematical logic.

---

> Note on "formally valid"
>
> Formally valid just means what it says, i.e. valid according to the outward form, or ostensive structure, of the argument, in contrast to the semantic content, or meaning, of the argument.

Comment: And argument with one false premise is always valid according to Ex Falso Quodlibet, a longtime fixture in classical logic. So something is lacking in this notion that validity is related only to form, or the notion of what constitutes form.  You can omit any premise you don't use, and False implies anything.  Again, present for Aristotle to talk about, so much, much older than the related math.

Comment: @jobermark Sure, it is clear something is lacking to formal logic as a whole, and this after 2,500 years of erudite investigation. But, I think there are very good reasons for that. Try to articulate a method to produce the same result as any of our thought processes... And we don't even know if human logic isn't somehow fundamentally flawed, making any "perfect" model irredeemably incorrect.

Comment: @We kind of do.  Russel's paradox exists.  And I am not sure what your comment has to do with my objection.  Your first sentence is false, the argument is formally valid in traditional systems.  It is not formally valid in more modern ones, but those generally don't use the term 'valid' in a formal sense anyway.

Comment: I actually don't think this answer deserves being downvoted--the OP wasn't clear whether or not to interpret question 1 as an argument or a statement. As a statement evaluated in the real world, it is formally true, but as Speakpigeon explains, as an argument is formally invalid.

Comment: Then again, OP did ask if it was "true or false" not "valid or invalid" so maybe this answer doesn't directly address the original question. Still, I think it's useful (if a bit unclear) so I'm upvoting.

Comment: @jobermark Sorry, I don't see the relation. Russell's paradox has nothing to do with a possible flaw in deductive logic or a problem with interpreting validity as based on form only. Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: @jobermark "*formally valid in traditional systems*":  I'm not sure which traditional systems you are referring to.The Stoics seem to have rejected arguments with false premises, for example. Aristotle can also be interpreted as suggesting broadly the same..Again, maybe you could elaborate.

Comment: @JohnHughes "*an argument or a statement*" It's a conditional, so it is both an argument, or implication, and a statement. And even if we assume the antecedent false, as probably does the OP, there is no good reason to say that the implication is true. Personally, I would scratch my head to find any good reason to qualify the implication as true. I guess I don't need to elaborate since this is what I already explained why in my answer.

Comment: If you don't see that Principia Mathematica, the system in which Russel discovered his paradox is a system of deductive logic, I cannot help you.  You seem not to take anyone else seriously, and to work to make other's question themselves while you refuse to do the same.  I will work harder to avoid you,

Comment: @Speakpigeon Luckily, just because one person can't think of a good reason doesn't mean there isn't one. And frankly, just because most people who aren't trained in logic don't think it should be valid doesn't mean it shouldn't be valid. Most people who aren't trained as surgeons wouldn't think it makes sense to remove my appendix. There are lots of good reasons in propositional logic for this conditional to evaluate to true, which have been rehashed extensively on this site.

Comment: Meanwhile Ex Falso Quodlibet goes back to Scotism, a major thread of Scholasticism, the basis for Boole.  Either Scholastic Aristotelian logic or Boolean logic is what is taught in almost all traditional canons today, and what is generally referred to as classical logic.  Enough elaboration?  You may present your own formalism, but declaring it to the rule is misleading and contrary to the spirit of philosophy.

Comment: @jobermark If you're not prepared to articulate your point, I can't do it for you. I'm not saying much but what I say is correct. If you think I'm wrong , it's up to you to explain yourself. If you have a rational argument, you're welcome to make it. Just don't expect me to take what you say on trust.

Comment: @JohnHughes Your surgeon analogy doesn't work with me. I guess if that's your best argument, you're not going to convince me. And I know the state of the art rather well. The fact of the matter is that there is no justification for accepting the idea that a false antecedent makes a valid argument. I took the time to look for one and didn't. The fact a number of self-appointed expert logicians decided that on balance it was the better option has zero value with me.

Comment: @jobermark You seem to take logic to be something like cricket, where I suppose if you want to play you better follow the rules the professional players are following. Well, logic ain't cricket. Logic isn't a bunch of rules cooked up by self-appointed logicians. I take my cues from people, human beings, and preferably not biased by any formal training. This seems a very reasonable angle and it seems to work.

Comment: @Speakpigeon  No, but I think that when you use a language they should not deviate severely from either the most common, or the documented standard usage.  The people who say 'formally valid' most often don't mean by it what you mean, nor is it the norm in documents.  It is like deciding dog means horse and going with it because it works for you.  Go ahead, but don't promote your solecisms as if you are an expert.

Comment: "If I have a rational argument"  -- this crosses the line into asshole territory.  Go ahead and be an asshole, but don't expect others to bow down to your attitude.

Comment: I don't even agree with the perspective of classical logc, but I don't act as though my positions are representative, thereby misrepresenting the history of logic as more logical than it is.  I admit that common usage is common usage, even when it is wrong.  And your usage of 'formally valid' is not the common usage.  so if this is 'like cricket', I am playing baseball, but **I know the difference**